# SSIS OLEDB connection not saving password when setting connection string from package configurations

Tags: ssis, connection-string, oledbconnection, ssis-connection-manager

I am setting up an SSIS project for testing. This project has a package where I manage some connections to SQL Server data bases, for doing this I use Package Configurations. Here I have a configuration that takes four connection strings from a table. Each is being mapped to connection string property of SSIS OLEDB connection (As shown in next image).

```
Data Source=********;User ID=******;Password=******;Initial Catalog=********;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;
```

[image]

When I turn off "Work offline" and test the connection it works, the problem is that when execute the solution it logs some errors that are releated with the incorrect login to the data base.
I tried to do some workaround for this by setting everything manually (without Package Configurations) and changing protection level to "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword" and it worked.
It seems that the password of the connection string is not being saved when being taken from package configurations.

Comment: Please show an example of connection string stored within the database?

Comment: Data Source=********;User ID=******;Password=******;Initial Catalog=********;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False; @Hadi